# Entity Framework - Preserving Data

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

Using Model First, what is the best way to approach preservation of existing database data when the model changes and the database has to be regenerated?

The Database Power Pack extension no longer works (I've been trying to contact the author). I can't find anything that provides similar functionality.

R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If database power pack doesn't work there is no other automatic way. Manual way requires running created SQL script on another database and using Visual Studio Database tools to create difference script between the current and the newly created database.